# Selecting specific JSON fields to use in SNS message

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to build a step function which receives json as input and then uses only some of this JSON in a message sent via SNS in the step function. I've tried using some of the [instrinsic json manipulation functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate) available but with no luck.
Is there a way to extract specific json fields for an SNS message without using a lambda?

For the message field, I would like the it to be:

```
  message.$: $.name $.questions etc...
```

But this doesn't work

Here is my code:

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    hellostepfunc1:
      name: test
      definition:
        Comment: "test"
        StartAt: SNSState
        States:
          SNSState:
            Type: Task
            InputPath: $
            Resource: arn:aws:states:::sns:publish
            Parameters:
              TopicArn:
                Fn::GetAtt: [ MyTopic, TopicArn ]
              Message.$: $ //here I would like to send multiple e.g $.name $questions
            End: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use an AWS Lambda function. That is, develop a custom AWS Lambda function that can read and manipulate JSON to meet your business requirments using a JSON library. Then hook these Lambda functions into an [Amazon States Language document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-amazon-states-language.html).